# Ansible using replace filter to replace any character between 2 consecutive word

Tags: ansible

can i know how can i replace any character between http://****: and @192.29.91.78:8080 with a ****. The condition is if it have https, :, @ and 192.29.91.78:8080, the value should be replaced to **** from : to @.

Below are my output sample and code. I would like to use a filter for this. If there a better solution, i open for it as well.

Jenkins output

```
TASK [Cloning From Bitbucket : Failed to clone from Bitbucket ***
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "fatal: unable to access 'http://****:myPssw0rd%40@192.29.91.78:8080/repo-name/repo-name.git/': Empty reply from server\n"}
```

My playbook code

```
  rescue:
  - name: Failed to clone from Bitbucket
    fail:
      msg: "{{ responseOutput.stderr }}"
```

I have tried this as well

```
    fail:
      msg: "{{ responseOutput.stderr | regex_replace('^http:.*:.*@$', 'http://****:****@') }}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex replace filter, like so,

```
fail:
  msg: "{{ errorMessage.stderr | regex_replace('^(.*http://\*\*\*\*:).*(@.*)$', '\\1****\\2') }}"
```

Comment: hi, need modify regex_replace('^(.*http:.*:).*(@.*)$', '\\1****\\2') else will hit error. thanks ya owrking fine. just to confirm \1 means the 1st bracket (.*http://\*\*\*\*:) wherease \2 means the second bracket (@.*). Correct?

Comment: Yes, \\1 represents first group, and so on